# How to name this organic isomer compound?

Tags: nomenclature

The chemical formula is C<sub>10</sub>H<sub>22</sub>O. I don't know how to assign which group gets priority when it is formulated this way. I think there is an iso- or sec- involved, but I'm not sure. I've looked at other questions for guidance but nothing is similar to this. I don't know where to go from here and where to start with naming this. Please lend help as to where to start.[image: organic compound with formula C10H22O]

Comment: Please consider punctuating the question nicely. It will surely improve it.

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry SE! Have a look at some of the [IUPAC recommendations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IUPAC_nomenclature_of_organic_chemistry).

Comment: "i believe the chemical formula is C10 H22 O, i think it is related or similar to 2-propylheptanol" – This looks like you just counted the atoms to get the molecular formula and then googled "C10H22O". This is not a useful approach in organic chemistry as your example nicely illustrates.

Comment: "i don't know how to assign which group gets priority" – That might be because there are zero groups in this compound that could get such kind of priority.

Comment: "i think there is an iso- or sec- involved" – No. And preferably, you don’t use “iso” and “sec” at all.

Answer (score 1):

You are right on this point: it is not an alcohol because there is no $\ce{-OH}$ group ; it is an ether oxide.
To name it, we are looking for the largest carbon chain: here it is $ \ce {CH_3 -CH_2 -CH_2-CH_2-CH_2-CH_2-CH_2-CH_3} $ with 8 carbon atoms so the suffix of the compound is octane.
We then add as a prefix the smallest carbon chain (here 2 carbon atoms so ethoxy) to which we add the number to indicate the position where the side chain is attached on the main chain (3 here) -> the prefix is therefore 3 -ethoxy
So ultimately your chemical is 3-ethoxyoctane

Comment: "octane" is not a suffix.